# Trying to use ESAPI getValidInput but getting error

Tags: validation, esapi

The following error is being generated while trying to validate an input:

```
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException SecurityConfiguration class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration) CTOR threw exception.
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.securityConfiguration(ESAPI.java:184)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.validator(ESAPI.java:191)
    at crypton.RSACripto.main(RSACripto.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:86)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: ESAPI.properties could not be loaded by any means. Fail.
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.loadConfiguration(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:439)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.<init>(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:227)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.getInstance(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:75)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load ESAPI.properties as a classloader resource.
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.loadConfigurationFromClasspath(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:653)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.loadConfiguration(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:436)
    ... 10 more
```

This happens at line:

```
    String validInput=ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("GetValidInput:", "hola.txt", "Validator.FileName", 10,false);
```

I have included the ESAPI configuration below:

```
 # ESAPI Configuration
 #
 # If true, then print all the ESAPI properties set here when they are loaded.
 # If false, they are not printed. Useful to reduce output when running JUnit tests.
 # If you need to troubleshoot a properties related problem, turning this on may help,
 # but we leave it off for running JUnit tests. (It will be 'true' in the one delivered
 # as part of production ESAPI, mostly for backward compatibility.)
 ESAPI.printProperties=false

 # ESAPI is designed to be easily extensible. You can use the reference implementation
 # or implement your own providers to take advantage of your enterprise's security
 # infrastructure. The functions in ESAPI are referenced using the ESAPI locator, like:
 #
 #    String ciphertext =
 #      ESAPI.encryptor().encrypt("Secret message");   // Deprecated in 2.0
 #    CipherText cipherText =
 #      ESAPI.encryptor().encrypt(new PlainText("Secret message")); // Preferred
 #
 # Below you can specify the classname for the provider that you wish to use in your
 # application. The only requirement is that it implement the appropriate ESAPI interface.
 # This allows you to switch security implementations in the future without rewriting the
 # entire application.
 #
 # ExperimentalAccessController requires ESAPI-AccessControlPolicy.xml in .esapi directory
 ESAPI.AccessControl=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultAccessController
 # FileBasedAuthenticator requires users.txt file in .esapi directory
 ESAPI.Authenticator=org.owasp.esapi.reference.FileBasedAuthenticator
 ESAPI.Encoder=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder
 ESAPI.Encryptor=org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto.JavaEncryptor

 ESAPI.Executor=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultExecutor
 ESAPI.HTTPUtilities=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities
 ESAPI.IntrusionDetector=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultIntrusionDetector
 # Log4JFactory Requires log4j.xml or log4j.properties in classpath - http://www.laliluna.de/log4j-tutorial.html
 ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogFactory
 #ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory
 #ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.reference.ExampleExtendedLog4JLogFactory
 ESAPI.Randomizer=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultRandomizer
 ESAPI.Validator=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator

 #===========================================================================
 # ESAPI Authenticator
 #
 Authenticator.AllowedLoginAttempts=3
 Authenticator.MaxOldPasswordHashes=13
 Authenticator.UsernameParameterName=username
 Authenticator.PasswordParameterName=password
 # RememberTokenDuration (in days)
 Authenticator.RememberTokenDuration=14
 # Session Timeouts (in minutes)
 Authenticator.IdleTimeoutDuration=20
 Authenticator.AbsoluteTimeoutDuration=120

 #===========================================================================
 # ESAPI Encoder
 #
 # ESAPI canonicalizes input before validation to prevent bypassing filters with encoded attacks.
 # Failure to canonicalize input is a very common mistake when implementing validation schemes.
 # Canonicalization is automatic when using the ESAPI Validator, but you can also use the
 # following code to canonicalize data.
 #
 #      ESAPI.Encoder().canonicalize( "%22hello world&#x22;" );
 #  
 # Multiple encoding is when a single encoding format is applied multiple times. Allowing
 # multiple encoding is strongly discouraged.
 Encoder.AllowMultipleEncoding=false

 # Mixed encoding is when multiple different encoding formats are applied, or when
 # multiple formats are nested. Allowing multiple encoding is strongly discouraged.
 Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding=false

 # The default list of codecs to apply when canonicalizing untrusted data. The list should include the codecs
 # for all downstream interpreters or decoders. For example, if the data is likely to end up in a URL, HTML, or
 # inside JavaScript, then the list of codecs below is appropriate. The order of the list is not terribly important.
 Encoder.DefaultCodecList=HTMLEntityCodec,PercentCodec,JavaScriptCodec


 #===========================================================================
 # ESAPI Encryption
 #
 # The ESAPI Encryptor provides basic cryptographic functions with a simplified API.
 # To get started, generate a new key using java -classpath esapi.jar org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto.JavaEncryptor
 # There is not currently any support for key rotation, so be careful when changing your key and salt as it
 # will invalidate all signed, encrypted, and hashed data.
 #
 # WARNING: Not all combinations of algorithms and key lengths are supported.
 # If you choose to use a key length greater than 128, you MUST download the
 # unlimited strength policy files and install in the lib directory of your JRE/JDK.
 # See http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp for more information.
 #
 # Backward compatibility with ESAPI Java 1.4 is supported by the two deprecated API
 # methods, Encryptor.encrypt(String) and Encryptor.decrypt(String). However, whenever
 # possible, these methods should be avoided as they use ECB cipher mode, which in almost
 # all circumstances a poor choice because of it's weakness. CBC cipher mode is the default
 # for the new Encryptor encrypt / decrypt methods for ESAPI Java 2.0.  In general, you
 # should only use this compatibility setting if you have persistent data encrypted with
 # version 1.4 and even then, you should ONLY set this compatibility mode UNTIL
 # you have decrypted all of your old encrypted data and then re-encrypted it with
 # ESAPI 2.0 using CBC mode. If you have some reason to mix the deprecated 1.4 mode
 # with the new 2.0 methods, make sure that you use the same cipher algorithm for both
 # (256-bit AES was the default for 1.4; 128-bit is the default for 2.0; see below for
 # more details.) Otherwise, you will have to use the new 2.0 encrypt / decrypt methods
 # where you can specify a SecretKey. (Note that if you are using the 256-bit AES,
 # that requires downloading the special jurisdiction policy files mentioned above.)
 #
 #      ***** IMPORTANT: These are for JUnit testing. Test files may have been
 #                       encrypted using these values so do not change these or
 #                       those tests will fail. The version under
 #                          src/main/resources/.esapi/ESAPI.properties
 #                       will be delivered with Encryptor.MasterKey and
 #                       Encryptor.MasterSalt set to the empty string.
 #
 #                       FINAL NOTE:
 #                           If Maven changes these when run, that needs to be fixed.
 #       256-bit key... requires unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files
 ### Encryptor.MasterKey=pJhlri8JbuFYDgkqtHmm9s0Ziug2PE7ovZDyEPm4j14=
 #       128-bit key
 Encryptor.MasterKey=a6H9is3hEVGKB4Jut+lOVA==
 Encryptor.MasterSalt=SbftnvmEWD5ZHHP+pX3fqugNysc=
 # Encryptor.MasterSalt=

 # Provides the default JCE provider that ESAPI will "prefer" for its symmetric
 # encryption and hashing. (That is it will look to this provider first, but it
 # will defer to other providers if the requested algorithm is not implemented
 # by this provider.) If left unset, ESAPI will just use your Java VM's current
 # preferred JCE provider, which is generally set in the file
 # "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security".
 #
 # The main intent of this is to allow ESAPI symmetric encryption to be
 # used with a FIPS 140-2 compliant crypto-module. For details, see the section
 # "Using ESAPI Symmetric Encryption with FIPS 140-2 Cryptographic Modules" in
 # the ESAPI 2.0 Symmetric Encryption User Guide, at:
 # http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/esapi4java-core-2.0-symmetric-crypto-user-guide.html
 # However, this property also allows you to easily use an alternate JCE provider
 # such as "Bouncy Castle" without having to make changes to "java.security".
 # See Javadoc for SecurityProviderLoader for further details. If you wish to use
 # a provider that is not known to SecurityProviderLoader, you may specify the
 # fully-qualified class name of the JCE provider class that implements
 # java.security.Provider. If the name contains a '.', this is interpreted as
 # a fully-qualified class name that implements java.security.Provider.
 #
 # NOTE: Setting this property has the side-effect of changing it in your application
 #       as well, so if you are using JCE in your application directly rather than
 #       through ESAPI (you wouldn't do that, would you? ;-), it will change the
 #       preferred JCE provider there as well.
 #
 # Default: Keeps the JCE provider set to whatever JVM sets it to.
 Encryptor.PreferredJCEProvider=

 # AES is the most widely used and strongest encryption algorithm. This
 # should agree with your Encryptor.CipherTransformation property.
 # By default, ESAPI Java 1.4 uses "PBEWithMD5AndDES" and which is
 # very weak. It is essentially a password-based encryption key, hashed
 # with MD5 around 1K times and then encrypted with the weak DES algorithm
 # (56-bits) using ECB mode and an unspecified padding (it is
 # JCE provider specific, but most likely "NoPadding"). However, 2.0 uses
 # "AES/CBC/PKCSPadding". If you want to change these, change them here.
 # Warning: This property does not control the default reference implementation for
 #         ESAPI 2.0 using JavaEncryptor. Also, this property will be dropped
 #         in the future.
 # @deprecated
 Encryptor.EncryptionAlgorithm=AES
 #      For ESAPI Java 2.0 - New encrypt / decrypt methods use this.
 Encryptor.CipherTransformation=AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

 # Applies to ESAPI 2.0 and later only!
 # Comma-separated list of cipher modes that provide *BOTH*
 # confidentiality *AND* message authenticity. (NIST refers to such cipher
 # modes as "combined modes" so that's what we shall call them.) If any of these
 # cipher modes are used then no MAC is calculated and stored
 # in the CipherText upon encryption. Likewise, if one of these
 # cipher modes is used with decryption, no attempt will be made
 # to validate the MAC contained in the CipherText object regardless
 # of whether it contains one or not. Since the expectation is that
 # these cipher modes support support message authenticity already,
 # injecting a MAC in the CipherText object would be at best redundant.
 #
 # Note that as of JDK 1.5, the SunJCE provider does not support *any*
 # of these cipher modes. Of these listed, only GCM and CCM are currently
 # NIST approved. YMMV for other JCE providers. E.g., Bouncy Castle supports
 # GCM and CCM with "NoPadding" mode, but not with "PKCS5Padding" or other
 # padding modes.
 Encryptor.cipher_modes.combined_modes=GCM,CCM,IAPM,EAX,OCB,CWC

 # Applies to ESAPI 2.0 and later only!
 # Additional cipher modes allowed for ESAPI 2.0 encryption. These
 # cipher modes are in _addition_ to those specified by the property
 # 'Encryptor.cipher_modes.combined_modes'.
 # Note: We will add support for streaming modes like CFB & OFB once
 # we add support for 'specified' to the property 'Encryptor.ChooseIVMethod'
 # (probably in ESAPI 2.1).
 #
 #  IMPORTANT NOTE: In the official ESAPI.properties we do *NOT* include ECB
 #                  here as this is an extremely weak mode. However, we *must*
 #                  allow it here so we can test ECB mode. That is important
 #                  since the logic is somewhat different (i.e., ECB mode does
 #                  not use an IV).
 # DISCUSS: Better name?
 #  NOTE: ECB added only for testing purposes. Don't try this at home!
 Encryptor.cipher_modes.additional_allowed=CBC,ECB

 # 128-bit is almost always sufficient and appears to be more resistant to
 # related key attacks than is 256-bit AES. Use '_' to use default key size
 # for cipher algorithms (where it makes sense because the algorithm supports
 # a variable key size). Key length must agree to what's provided as the
 # cipher transformation, otherwise this will be ignored after logging a
 # warning.
 #
 # NOTE: This is what applies BOTH ESAPI 1.4 and 2.0. See warning above about mixing!
 Encryptor.EncryptionKeyLength=128

 # Because 2.0 uses CBC mode by default, it requires an initialization vector (IV).
 # (All cipher modes except ECB require an IV.) There are two choices: we can either
 # use a fixed IV known to both parties or allow ESAPI to choose a random IV. While
 # the IV does not need to be hidden from adversaries, it is important that the
 # adversary not be allowed to choose it. Also, random IVs are generally much more
 # secure than fixed IVs. (In fact, it is essential that feed-back cipher modes
 # such as CFB and OFB use a different IV for each encryption with a given key so
 # in such cases, random IVs are much preferred. By default, ESAPI 2.0 uses random
 # IVs. If you wish to use 'fixed' IVs, set 'Encryptor.ChooseIVMethod=fixed' and
 # uncomment the Encryptor.fixedIV.
 #
 # Valid values:        random|fixed|specified      'specified' not yet implemented; planned for 2.1
 Encryptor.ChooseIVMethod=random
 # If you choose to use a fixed IV, then you must place a fixed IV here that
 # is known to all others who are sharing your secret key. The format should
 # be a hex string that is the same length as the cipher block size for the
 # cipher algorithm that you are using. The following is an example for AES
 # from an AES test vector for AES-128/CBC as described in:
 # NIST Special Publication 800-38A (2001 Edition)
 # "Recommendation for Block Cipher Modes of Operation".
 # (Note that the block size for AES is 16 bytes == 128 bits.)
 #
 Encryptor.fixedIV=0x000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f

 # Whether or not CipherText should use a message authentication code (MAC) with it.
 # This prevents an adversary from altering the IV as well as allowing a more
 # fool-proof way of determining the decryption failed because of an incorrect
 # key being supplied. This refers to the "separate" MAC calculated and stored
 # in CipherText, not part of any MAC that is calculated as a result of a
 # "combined mode" cipher mode.
 #
 # If you are using ESAPI with a FIPS 140-2 cryptographic module, you *must* also
 # set this property to false.
 Encryptor.CipherText.useMAC=true

 # Whether or not the PlainText object may be overwritten and then marked
 # eligible for garbage collection. If not set, this is still treated as 'true'.
 Encryptor.PlainText.overwrite=true

 # Do not use DES except in a legacy situations. 56-bit is way too small key size.
 #Encryptor.EncryptionKeyLength=56
 #Encryptor.EncryptionAlgorithm=DES

 # TripleDES is considered strong enough for most purposes.
 #  Note:   There is also a 112-bit version of DESede. Using the 168-bit version
 #          requires downloading the special jurisdiction policy from Sun.
 #Encryptor.EncryptionKeyLength=168
 #Encryptor.EncryptionAlgorithm=DESede

 Encryptor.HashAlgorithm=SHA-512
 Encryptor.HashIterations=1024
 Encryptor.DigitalSignatureAlgorithm=SHA1withDSA
 Encryptor.DigitalSignatureKeyLength=1024
 Encryptor.RandomAlgorithm=SHA1PRNG
 Encryptor.CharacterEncoding=UTF-8
 # Currently supported choices for JDK 1.5 and 1.6 are:
 #  HmacSHA1 (160 bits), HmacSHA256 (256 bits), HmacSHA384 (384 bits), and
 #  HmacSHA512 (512 bits).
 # Note that HmacMD5 is *not* supported for the PRF used by the KDF even though
 # these JDKs support it.
 Encryptor.KDF.PRF=HmacSHA256

 #===========================================================================
 # ESAPI HttpUtilties
 #
 # The HttpUtilities provide basic protections to HTTP requests and responses. Primarily these methods 
 # protect against malicious data from attackers, such as unprintable characters, escaped characters,
 # and other simple attacks. The HttpUtilities also provides utility methods for dealing with cookies,
 # headers, and CSRF tokens.
 #
 # Default file upload location (remember to escape backslashes with \\)
 HttpUtilities.UploadDir=C\:\\ESAPI\\testUpload
 # let this default to java.io.tmpdir for testing
 #HttpUtilities.UploadTempDir=C:\\temp
 # Force flags on cookies, if you use HttpUtilities to set cookies
 HttpUtilities.ForceHttpOnlySession=false
 HttpUtilities.ForceSecureSession=false
 HttpUtilities.ForceHttpOnlyCookies=true
 HttpUtilities.ForceSecureCookies=true
 # Maximum size of HTTP headers
 HttpUtilities.MaxHeaderSize=4096
 # File upload configuration
 HttpUtilities.ApprovedUploadExtensions=.zip,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.ppt,.pptx,.tar,.gz,.tgz,.rar,.war,.jar,.ear,.xls,.rtf,.properties,.java,.class,.txt,.xml,.jsp,.jsf,.exe,.dll
 HttpUtilities.MaxUploadFileBytes=500000000
 # Using UTF-8 throughout your stack is highly recommended. That includes your database driver,
 # container, and any other technologies you may be using. Failure to do this may expose you
 # to Unicode transcoding injection attacks. Use of UTF-8 does not hinder internationalization.
 HttpUtilities.ResponseContentType=text/html; charset=UTF-8
 # This is the name of the cookie used to represent the HTTP session
 # Typically this will be the default "JSESSIONID" 
 HttpUtilities.HttpSessionIdName=JSESSIONID



 #===========================================================================
 # ESAPI Executor
 # CHECKME - Not sure what this is used for, but surely it should be made OS independent.
 Executor.WorkingDirectory=C\:\\Windows\\Temp
 Executor.ApprovedExecutables=C\:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe,C\:\\Windows\\System32\\runas.exe


 #===========================================================================
 # ESAPI Logging
 # Set the application name if these logs are combined with other applications
 Logger.ApplicationName=ExampleApplication
 # If you use an HTML log viewer that does not properly HTML escape log data, you can set LogEncodingRequired to true
 Logger.LogEncodingRequired=false
 # Determines whether ESAPI should log the application name. This might be clutter in some single-server/single-app environments.
 Logger.LogApplicationName=true
 # Determines whether ESAPI should log the server IP and port. This might be clutter in some single-server environments.
 Logger.LogServerIP=true
 # LogFileName, the name of the logging file. Provide a full directory path (e.g., C:\\ESAPI\\ESAPI_logging_file) if you
 # want to place it in a specific directory.
 Logger.LogFileName=ESAPI_logging_file
 # MaxLogFileSize, the max size (in bytes) of a single log file before it cuts over to a new one (default is 10,000,000)
 Logger.MaxLogFileSize=10000000


 #===========================================================================
 # ESAPI Intrusion Detection
 #
 # Each event has a base to which .count, .interval, and .action are added
 # The IntrusionException will fire if we receive "count" events within "interval" seconds
 # The IntrusionDetector is configurable to take the following actions: log, logout, and disable
 #  (multiple actions separated by commas are allowed e.g. event.test.actions=log,disable
 #
 # Custom Events
 # Names must start with "event." as the base
 # Use IntrusionDetector.addEvent( "test" ) in your code to trigger "event.test" here
 # You can also disable intrusion detection completely by changing
 # the following parameter to true
 #
 IntrusionDetector.Disable=false
 #
 IntrusionDetector.event.test.count=2
 IntrusionDetector.event.test.interval=10
 IntrusionDetector.event.test.actions=disable,log

 # Exception Events
 # All EnterpriseSecurityExceptions are registered automatically
 # Call IntrusionDetector.getInstance().addException(e) for Exceptions that do not extend EnterpriseSecurityException
 # Use the fully qualified classname of the exception as the base

 # any intrusion is an attack
 IntrusionDetector.org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntrusionException.count=1
 IntrusionDetector.org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntrusionException.interval=1 IntrusionDetector.org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntrusionException.actions=log,disable,logout

 # for test purposes
 # CHECKME: Shouldn't there be something in the property name itself that designates
 #         that these are for testing???
 IntrusionDetector.org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntegrityException.count=10
 IntrusionDetector.org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntegrityException.interval=5
 IntrusionDetector.org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntegrityException.actions=log,disable,logout

 # rapid validation errors indicate scans or attacks in progress
 # org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException.count=10
 # org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException.interval=10
 # org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException.actions=log,logout

 # sessions jumping between hosts indicates session hijacking
 IntrusionDetector.org.owasp.esapi.errors.AuthenticationHostException.count=2
 IntrusionDetector.org.owasp.esapi.errors.AuthenticationHostException.interval=10
 IntrusionDetector.org.owasp.esapi.errors.AuthenticationHostException.actions=log,logout


 #===========================================================================
 # ESAPI Validation
 #
 # The ESAPI Validator works on regular expressions with defined names. You can define names
 # either here, or you may define application specific patterns in a separate file defined below.
 # This allows enterprises to specify both organizational standards as well as application specific
 # validation rules.
 #
 Validator.ConfigurationFile=validation.properties

 # Validators used by ESAPI
 Validator.AccountName=^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$
 Validator.SystemCommand=^[a-zA-Z\\-\\/]{1,64}$
 Validator.RoleName=^[a-z]{1,20}$
 Validator.Redirect=^(/[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]*)*?[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_\=&]*$

 # Global HTTP Validation Rules
 # Values with Base64 encoded data (e.g. encrypted state) will need at least [a-zA-Z0-9\/+=]
 Validator.HTTPScheme=^(http|https)$
 Validator.HTTPServerName=^[a-zA-Z0-9_.\\-]*$
 Validator.HTTPCookieName=^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]{1,32}$
 Validator.HTTPCookieValue=^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\/+\=_ ]*$
 Validator.HTTPHeaderName=^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]{1,32}$
 Validator.HTTPHeaderValue=^[a-zA-Z0-9()\\-\=\\*\\.\\?;,+\\/\:&_ ]*$
 Validator.HTTPServletPath=^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-\\/_]*$
 Validator.HTTPPath=^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]*$
 Validator.HTTPURL=^.*$
 Validator.HTTPJSESSIONID=^[A-Z0-9]{10,30}$

 # Contributed by Fraenku@gmx.ch
 # Googlecode Issue 116 (http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/issues/detail?id=116)
 Validator.HTTPParameterName=^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-]{1,32}$
 Validator.HTTPParameterValue=^[\\p{L}\\p{N}.\\-/+\=_ \!$*?@]{0,1000}$
 Validator.HTTPContextPath=^/[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]*$
 Validator.HTTPQueryString=^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-]{1,32}\=[\\p{L}\\p{N}.\\-/+\=_\!$*?@%]*&?)*$
 Validator.HTTPURI=^(/[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]*)*?[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_\=&]*$


 # Validation of file related input
 Validator.FileName=^[a-zA-Z0-9(.|\\|/|-|' ')]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
 Validator.DirectoryName=^[a-zA-Z0-9\:/\\\\\!@\#$%^&{}\\[\\]()_+\\-\=,.~'`]{1,255}$

 # Validation of dates. Controls whether or not 'lenient' dates are accepted.
 # See DataFormat.setLenient(boolean flag) for further details.
 Validator.AcceptLenientDates=false
```

My research seems to indicate that it has something to do with the ESAPI properties file but I have the properties file in the same folder as the jar is and it doesn't work.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Solved, i just had to add to my classpath project the folder which has the property file and just worked, now i have a differente error but that's fine

Comment: I've made a large number of edits to your file to reformat it properly.  Please take note that you have left your master key in the configuration file that you published here.  This was likely an error.  You will definitely want to change that out in the code that you use in production.

Comment: Thank your very much, actually we don't use ESAPI for coding our information and we don't use aes so that's not my master key but i didn't realiced about that, i'll eliminate it We use a keysotre generated by keytools as it's sugested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can out it in your web apps root source folder (src). Do not put it in any package. For me just empty file worked out. Though it searched other places too. You can refer following logs -

```
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/ESAPI.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi/ESAPI.properties
Not found in 'user.home' (/Users/athakur) directory: /Users/athakur/esapi/ESAPI.properties
Loading ESAPI.properties via file I/O failed. Exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.
SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ESAPI.properties via the CLASSPATH from '/ (root)' using current thread context class loader!
SecurityConfiguration for Validator.ConfigurationFile not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: validation.properties
Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/validation.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi/validation.properties
Not found in 'user.home' (/Users/athakur) directory: /Users/athakur/esapi/validation.properties
Loading validation.properties via file I/O failed.
Attempting to load validation.properties via the classpath.
validation.properties could not be loaded by any means. fail. Exception was: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load ESAPI.properties as a classloader resource.
SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.printProperties not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false
SecurityConfiguration for Encryptor.CipherTransformation not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.Encoder not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder
SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.Logger not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory
SecurityConfiguration for Logger.LogApplicationName not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: true
SecurityConfiguration for Logger.LogServerIP not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: true
SecurityConfiguration for Logger.ApplicationName not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: DefaultName
```

Based on above logs I create a empty ESAPI.properties file in root directory of source folder and added following contents in it -

```
ESAPI.printProperties=true
Encryptor.CipherTransformation=AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
ESAPI.Encoder=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder
# Log4JFactory Requires log4j.xml or log4j.properties in classpath - http://www.laliluna.de/log4j-tutorial.html
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogFactory
# Determines whether ESAPI should log the application name. This might be clutter in some single-server/single-app environments.
Logger.LogApplicationName=true
# Determines whether ESAPI should log the server IP and port. This might be clutter in some single-server environments.
Logger.LogServerIP=true
# Set the application name if these logs are combined with other applications
Logger.ApplicationName=ExampleApplication
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved, I just had to add to my classpath project the folder which has the property file and it just worked. Now I have a different error, but that's fine.

Comment: How did you add the classpath? I'm using Intellij and the old Spring MVC (web.xml).

Comment: I never used that Ide, sorry, I used eclipse and now vscode.... hope someone else can help you.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your time.